# Remove word if it starts with - or --

Tags: regex, bash, sed

What I want to do is in the title.

Input:

```
apple -berry --sun house-roof computer-- orange number-43
```

Desired output:

```
apple house-roof computer-- orange number-43
```

In other words, only when a word starts with `-` or `--` it should be removed. The closest I've got is:

```
echo "apple -berry --sun house-roof computer-- orange number-43" | sed -r 's/(-|--)\w+//g'
apple   house computer-- orange number
```

Which is far from what I want. Could be solved with other tools? Cut?

Comment: Do you want to keep words that begin with 3 or more hyphens (e.g. `---moon`)?  What about words that contain only a single or double hyphen (`-` or `--`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/(^|[[:space:]]+)-{1,2}[^[:space:]]+//g'
```

*Details*:

- `-E` enables the POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `(^|[[:space:]]+)-{1,2}[^[:space:]]+` - matches

  - `(^|[[:space:]]+)` - start of string or one or more whitespaces
  - `-{1,2}` - one or two hyphens
  - `[^[:space:]]+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/uA6ueZ):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='apple -berry --sun house-roof computer-- orange number-43'
sed -E 's/(^|[[:space:]]+)-{1,2}[^[:space:]]+//g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
apple house-roof computer-- orange number-43
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by converting each token to a line and then `grep`ing with a negated pattern.

For example:

```sh
xargs -n1 <input.txt | grep -v -E -e '^-[-]?[[:alnum:]]' | xargs
```

Answer (score 0):

plain bash:

```sh
input="apple -berry --sun house-roof computer-- orange number-43"
read -ra words <<< "$input"
ok_words=()
for word in "${words[@]}"; do
    [[ $word == @(-|--)* ]] || ok_words+=("$word")
done
echo "${ok_words[*]}"
```

```
apple house-roof computer-- orange number-43
```

`@(-|--)` is an [extended pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) matching *either* `-` *or* `--`

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, going through each field value of each line and checking condition if field is NOT starting from either `-` OR `--` then add its value to variable `line` at last print the value of line(`awk` variable, which is being nullified before `for` loop starts).

```
awk '
{
  line=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i!~/^-[^-]/ && $i!~/^--[^-]/){
      line=(line?line OFS:"") $i
    }
  }
  print line
}
' Input_file
```